# How to say “cooties” in French?

Tags: traduction, anglais, vocabulaire, enfants

Cooties (occasionally spelled *coodies*) is an imaginary disease that little boys say little girls have.

Comment: And what's the subtle difference between _[Cootie](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=cootie)_ and _[Coodies](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=coodies)_?

Comment: @Stamm I'm fairly sure it's just a variant spelling because the /t/ [becomes a flap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intervocalic_alveolar-flapping) in that word.

Comment: Imaginary? Little girls only? *Damn!* And I've been applying anti-cootie lotion every day for decades.

Comment: @Drew Si un jeune enfant est infesté de poux et donc infecté de cette grave maladie, est-il destiné à devenir infect plus tard (comme le lien entre la varicelle et le zona)? Punaise, ça expliquerait pas mal de chose, quand même!

Comment: I'm older and from the southern USA . This word has been around all my life. Refers to imaginary bugs. Think head lice. Connotes uncleanliness. Usually uttered in jest referring to girl or boy.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To the best of my knowledge, there is no such thing as an equivalent to "cooties" in French "childhood culture", either in Europe or North America. You might find references to the other sex being icky, but I have never seen it "formalized" as something like it is in English.

Answer (score 12):

I'm French.
The best translation I can think of is (as, apparently, "cooties" is an insult boys use against girls) "les filles c'est nul" or "les filles ça craint" (not "ça craint = it scares" but "ça craint = it's the shame of being with, it's boring". Literary translation would be "les filles c'est des pouilleuses", "the girls are dirty / verminous persons", but it is not something children say in real life. This is too "nasty" and saying that would probably result in the children being scolded by their parents; saying "les filles c'est nul" might make parents smile.

Comment: The local variant I heard is *des pisseuses*, it refers to little girls, but it's not used by little boys, mostly grown-ups, and it's pejorative also.

Comment: [Cooties](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cooties) (Wikipedia) do **not** apply only to girls.

Answer (score 2):

A possible translation for “cooties” (which works for speakers from Québec or Europe) would be « des microbes de fille ».

Answer (score -1):

In French, we would use something like "la touche pas, elle a des poux" (don't touch her, she has lice).

Comment: I've never heard anything of the sort...

Comment: *louses* -> *lice*

Comment: Mais tu comprends bien que les "cooties" en anglais, ils ne indiquent pas une vraie infestation en ce moment?

Answer (score -1):

Je ne connais pas l'expression anglaise, mais en France quand j'étais gamin j'entendais souvent les garçons moquer les filles en les qualifiant de *pisseuses*.